# windows RabbitMQ doesnt have rabbitmqadmin in sbin folder

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmqadmin

I am working on RabbitMQ in windows environment.Do we have rabbitmqadmin for windows as well?

i am not able to find rabbitmqadmin in sbin folder of rabbitmq.

please let me know .

Answer (score 10):

You will not find rabbitmqadmin in sbin. You need to do following to get it working on windows

1. You need python installed on your windows machine.
   Follow this link to download and install python : https://www.python.org/downloads/
2. Once installed, update system env variable path by adding python installation path to existing value.
3. Check the installation and path setting has correctly by using this command `python`. It should open command line editor
4. Browse to http://{host}:15672/cli/ to download rabbitmqadmin, save it without extension
5. Now open the command prompt, change your directory to rabbitmqadmin downloaded directory and execute below command:

   python.exe rabbitmqadmin --help

If you see the helps are shown in response of above command then you are all set to perform various rabbitmqadmin operations!

Comment: at bullet 4:  Browse to http://localhost:15672/cli/ to download rabbitmqadmin, save it without extension. (spotted by anonymous user).

Comment: And there is error in switch. should be `python.exe rabbitmqadmin --help` (not `--helps`). Would edit the answer, but edited content is too short :/